# Weakmap reference lost in inheritance

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, private-members

I encountered a problem while working with private members of classes in javascript, which I cannot solve myself.

```
"use strict";
var privateData = new WeakMap();


class Fruit{
    constructor(name){
        privateData.set(this, {name: name});
    }

    name(){
        return privateData.get(this).name;
    }
}

class Orange extends Fruit{
    constructor(){
        super("Orange");
    privateData.set(this, {color: "blue"});
    }

    color(){
        return privateData.get(this).color;
    }
}

var fruit = new Fruit("Apple");
alert(fruit.name());
var orange = new Orange();
alert(orange.name());
```

First Output: Apple
Second Output: undefined

My guess is, I'm overwriting 'this', because if I delete

```
return privateData.get(this).color;
```

it works.

Comment: You are changing the value to `{color: 'blue'}`, hence accessing `name` later returns `undefined`. WeakMap does not magically merge the values.

Comment: Why the hassle with "private members" at all? You hardly do need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, objects are unique, and you are using the `this` instance as a key twice. The second `set` call will overwrite the value from the first call, and only leave the object with the `.color` property.

The easiest solution would be to use one weak map per attribute:

```
var privateNames = new WeakMap();
class Fruit {
    constructor(name) {
        privateNames.set(this, name);
    }
    get name() {
        return privateNames.get(this);
    }
}

var privateColors = new WeakMap();
class Orange extends Fruit {
    constructor() {
        super("Orange");
        privateColors.set(this, "blue");
    }
    get color() {
        return privateColors.get(this);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you will have to mutate the stored `data` object:

```
var privateData = new WeakMap();
class Fruit {
    constructor(name) {
        privateData.set(this, {name: name});
    }
    get name() {
        return privateData.get(this).name;
    }
}

class Orange extends Fruit {
    constructor() {
        super("Orange");
        privateData.get(this).color = "blue";
    }
    get color() {
        return privateData.get(this).color;
    }
}
```